# Java regex pattern for number

Tags: java, regex, match

I know that this question can be stupid but I am trying to get some information from text and you are my last hope after last three hours of trying..

```
DIC: C/40764176 IC: 407641'6 
Dekujerne a t8ime se na shledanou
```

I need to get for example this **40764176**

I need to get string with 8-10 length, sometimes there can be some special chars like I,i,G,S,O,ó,l) but I have tried a lot of patterns for this and no one works...

I tried:

```
String generalDicFormatPattern = "([0-9IiGSOól]{8,10})";
String generalDicFormatPattern = ".*([0-9IiGSOól]{8,10}).*";
String generalDicFormatPattern = "\\b([0-9IiGSOól]{8,10})\\b";
```

nothing works... do you know where is the problem?

edit:

I use regex in this way:

```
private List<String> getGeneralDicFromLine(String concreteLine) {
    List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(generalDicFormatPattern);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(concreteLine);

        while (matcher.find()) {             
             allMatches.add(matcher.group(1));
        }                           


    return allMatches;
}
```

Comment: Could you show us how you use your regex?

Comment: Your first and last regex works fine for me http://ideone.com/yOLK3O or maybe it is not correct output?

Comment: It is right output, I will try it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your string's pattern is fixed you can use the regex

```
C/([^\s]{8,10})\sIC:
```

Sample code:

```
String s = "DIC: C/40764176 IC: 407641'6";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("C/([^\\s]{8,10})\\sIC:");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1)); // 40764176
}
```

I'm expecting any character (includes the special ones you've shown in examples) but a white space.

Comment: No, I need to get string with 8-10 length which contains mainly numbers, but sometimes there can be some special chars like I,i,G,S,O,ó,l.. so for example I would like to get 123i56ó89

Comment: For a string `DIC: C/123i56ó89 IC: 407641'6` program outputs `123i56ó89`. So, it's covered.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can split your string with spaces (`string.split('\\s');`), then you should have an array like this :

1. DIC:
2. C/40764176
3. IC: 407641'6
4. ...
5. shledanou

Get the second string, split it using '/', and get the second element.

I hope it helped you.

Tip : you can check after the result using a regex (`([0-9IiGSOól]{8,10}`)